# Getting a ringtone to only loop once in mediaPlayer

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

So basically I use a Spinner widget and pass it the RingtoneManager Picker action, the user then selects their ringtone. Then I call onActivityResult() and get the uri for the ringtone.
Finally I pass the uri to another activity where I have a alarm setup to go off after a specific amount of time.

THE PROBLEM >>> when I get the uri for the ringtone in the 2nd activity and let mediaPlayer play it, It...it doesn't stop. No matter WHAT I try.

This is the 2nd activity and the mediaPlayer that never stops.

```
                    Uri ringtone;
                    ringtone = Uri.parse(musixType);
                    //mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(DisplayNotification.this, ringtone);
                    mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(DisplayNotification.this, ringtone);
                    mMediaPlayer.start();
                    mMediaPlayer.setVolume(100, 100);
            }
            mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

                    while (mMediaPlayer != null) {
                        mMediaPlayer.stop();
                        mMediaPlayer.release();
                        mMediaPlayer = null;
                    }
                }
            });
```

How do I get it to stop @.@

Edit:
Could the reason it doesn't stop playing be that it is a ringtone from the RingtoneManager? I don't know why this would matter but I'm grasping at straws at this point.

Edit:
Is there a way to specify a certain length of time for mediaPlayer to run and disregard the data passed to it?

Comment: Try to print the value of `isLooping()`  on the `mMediaPlayer` reference, see what you get.

Comment: The problem is, it's never getting to the onCompletionListener() method. I'm not sure since it's a ringtone if it's meant to just repeat over and over, but I sent mediaPlayer a uri so that shouldn't matter..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're not calling `setLooping(true);` on your `mMediaPlayer` referenced object, looping should not be the issue here as default is set `false`. Make sure you're not actually calling this piece of code multiple times from outside. Put a `Log` line before `mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(DisplayNotification.this, ringtone);` and see how many times it gets logged.

Comment: Thats what I thought at first too. But when I select the ringtone from the list of ringtones on the RingtoneManager, they also display the same looping behavior. So now I know that the actual ringtone I'm passing is looping instinctively. I have no idea how to change that as it is part of the AudioStore in android :(

I've updated my question with a more specific question

Comment: I suppose I could create an instance of alarmManager and set an alarm that shuts off the mediaPlayer after 5 seconds. Seems ridiculous, but hah. I think I'll probably do that. Thanks for your response, it helped me the most

Comment: You can also use a an invisible `Chronometer` in your XML:     `<Chronometer
 android:id="@+id/chrono" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:visibility="gone" />` and then work with that to count and enable/disable things based on the `onChronometerTick` events.

Answer (score 2):

did you use [MediaPlayer.setLooping](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setLooping%28boolean%29) method

use `mMediaPlayer.setLooping(false);`

Comment: yyuuppp. haha. I'm stumped.

Answer (score 0):

use this

mMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too and solved it like this:

```
player.setDataSource(this, ringtone);
player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
player.prepareAsync();
 player.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(final MediaPlayer mp) {
        myHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mp.stop();
                mp.release();
            }
        }, mp.getDuration()); <-- Make a postDelayed runnable that has the duration of the file as its cut off. Once the song plays, it will stop the mediaPlayer.
        mp.start();
    }
});
```